# Supervised learning dataset for click prediction in real time ad bidding

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, supervised-learning

I have a dataset of real time bidding events (programmatic advertising) with the following properties:

- Dataset spans a period of several consecutive weeks.
- 250M total bids.
- The winning percentage is 20% (80% of the time, the bid was too low, and someone else won the auction).
- Of the winning auctions, 0.06% of them resulted in a click.

## Question

I'm trying to train a model to learn which actions will result in a click. Certainly, there are observations (bids) in the dataset that would have resulted in a click, but the bid was too low, and someone else won that auction. But from the dataset's perspective, `click = false`.

So... should the training set only include bids that were won (and thus a click is possible)?

The ultimate goal is to have the model predict that a given auction **is not** likely to result in a click, thus one would not want to bid (the second step would be to have another model to predict the worth of the auction, such that the bidding agent would possibly increase its bid - thus increasing the odds of winning the auction - but that's a separate discussion).

Answer (score 0):

There might be some unsupervised way to use the data points corresponding to lost bids, but that seems challenging. One possibility is semisupervised learning, but in general that is tricky in practice.

I would suggest limiting your training and test sets to the bins that were won.